# search form with django+python

Tags: python, django, search

I have just started to do a website with django + python and I want to implement a search form to be able to search on all my database objects. What I want is; when I write for an example `S` I want the search field to display all my objects that starts with the letter `S` in a list, just like the Tags field below on this site.

Does anyone have a good ide to implement this with django?

Comment: just a simple search:
f = searchForm(request.POST)
...
pages = Page.objects.filter(name__contains = f.cleaned_data["text"])

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a decent django search implementation, I would recommend looking at `djapian`. However, for what you are doing, I would recommend a query using the `ISTARTSWITH` parameter. Consider the following:

**views.py**

```
def search(req):
    if req.GET:
        search_term = req.GET['term']
        results = ModelToSearch.objects.filter(field__istartswith=search_term)
        return render_to_response('search.html', {'results': results})
    return render_to_response('search.html', {})
```

**search.html**

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
     <input name='S'>
</form>
{% if results %}
Found the following items:
<ol>
{% for result in results %}
    <li>{{result}}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ol>
{% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```