# django search in db for similar entries my string name

Tags: python, django, search

I would like to build following app with Python + Django:

mydb: it is database of entries originally defined by me.
new entry: a new entry with any name of it for example: John
           each entry has got some parameters for example: p1, p2, p3

when I add new entry I type in a box and while typing its name I search through mydb for all similar (similar name starting with J) entries.

for example:
mydb has got following entries:

John
Jade
Jack
Kate

while typing a new entry when i type J it lists Jade, Jack, John so it's got similar functionality as google search engine or here stackoverflow search for similar tags while defining a tag.

if I find exact entry in mydb than I choose it.
if I do not find same entry in mydb I can define new entry with parameters p1, p2, p3.

I know at the moment how to creat a todo app with django so I can add new entries and edit them but I struggle with search funcionality as described below.

Could somebody point me to right direction what knowledge to gather, what examples to follow ?

I have found this old post dated 2010 but I am curious if there is anything better, newer: 
[search form with django+python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304837/search-form-with-djangopython)

I have some knowledge of Python, Django, PostgreSQL only at the moment.

Many thanks.

Comment: This link might help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304837/search-form-with-djangopython?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to learn some Javascript to learn how to interact with a search box on a page. You can write a django view to obtain the similar entries you need (it has to query the database). Make javascript call the django view (AJAX) to determine what entries to display.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need [Haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/) to do db search. To achieve the interactive search effect, you would also need javascript or jQuery to do Ajax calls.